# How does UIButton addTarget self work?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, self, addtarget

I try figure out why `self` point to the GameViewController instead of Answer

**GameViewController.swift**

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    var gameplay = QuestionsController(colors: colors)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(gameplay.answersController.answers[0].button)
    }

    func didPressAnswerButton(sender: UIButton!) {
        sender.setTitle("Im from GameViewController class", forState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

**QuestionsController.swift**

```
class QuestionsController {
    var question: Question
    var answersController: AnswersController
}
```

**AnswersController.swift**

```
class AnswersController {
    var answers = [Answer]()

    func prepareAnswers() {
        let answer = Answer()
        answers.append(answer)
    }
}
```

**Answer.swift**

```
class Answer{
    let button: UIButton

    func prepareButton() {
        let answerButton = AnswerButton(type: .System)
        answerButton.addTarget(self, action: "didPressAnswerButton:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        button = answerButton
    }

    func didPressAnswerButton(sender: UIButton!) {
        sender.setTitle("Im from Answer class", forState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget:action:forControlEvents:) tells the control (`answerButton` in this case) *what method* to call, and *what object* to call it on, when the user taps the button. Looking at your code in more detail:

```
 answerButton.addTarget(self, action: "didPressAnswerButton:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

- When the user taps a button, the `TouchUpInside` event fires on the `answerButton`, and when that happens we want to invoke a method `didPressAnswerButton:` on an `Answer` object
- So, we need to tell `answerButton` what do do when this TouchUpEvent fires. You do this calling the `addTarget:action:forControlEvents` method on the `answerButton`
- The `self` argument tells the `answerButton` what object to notify about the event: it is the *target*. In this context, `self` is an `Answer` object.
- The `"didPressAnswerButton:"` argument indicates what method the answerButton should call in response to the tap event: this is the *action*

This is the [target-action mechanism](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Target-Action/Target-Action.html) of Objective-C/Cocoa. It's a very common pattern, it's worth it to read the linked documentation to learn a bit more about how it works. The key is that this is based on Objective-C* message passing: in the code above, `"didPressAnswerButton:"` indicates a *selector*, which when paired with a target (`self`), tells the answerButton how to send a "message" to the target when the user taps the button.

Also, note that when you are editing a storyboard and ctrl-drag from a button to your view controller and select a method, you are also setting up a target/action using this same mechanism. You select the target object by dragging to the view controller icon (or some other icon), and then you pick the action/selector when clicking on a method name in the popup.

* Target-Action was originally designed for Objective-C, but for the common case of implementing a view controller, you can assume Swift works the same way. Just note when reading documentation that Swift uses simple strings for actions, whereas Objective-C uses `@selector(...)`.